# How to remove graphics driver

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, xorg

recently i turned over to Linux from Windows . 
There was a problem because Linux wouldn't show my Nvdia GPU with the lscpi command i would only get my VGA as intel chipset . After that and a little scavenging i did , i manage to figure out a way (add "xorg-edgers" repository then update it and i would find the drivers i needed in the "additional drivers" . Well that worked , but about 1 hour later from me  doing that the driver started crashing and i had to fall back to a ctrl+alt+f1 shell in which i rebooted my laptop (Asus X550LN) .

Q: how can i disable that from the shell and put intel back in ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove the Nvidia proprietary driver by running in terminal

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*
```

I also suggest removing xorg-edgers ppa too. It can be done by

```
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
sudo ppa-purge ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
```

But I suggest installing proprietary Nvidia driver with nvidia-prime.

If you choose the right driver and install it correctly, you will always be able to switch to Nvidia or Intel GPU.

If you do not do this, both adapters will consume power. You will get overheating and low battery life.

Comment: thnx a lot , that did the trick =p , which is tho the correct driver ? i picked up the latest one ...

Comment: @ΠέτροςΙωσηφίδης It depends on Ubuntu version and adapter model.